# How to convert a dynamically added property(using metaClass) to JSON

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I am trying to add a dynamic property to each instance of a class and then convert a list of such objects to json. Refer to the example below

```
class Author{
    String name
    static hasMany=[books:Book]
}

class Book{
    String title
    static belongsTo=[author:Author]
}

my controller

class AuthorController{
    def listAuthors={
        def authorsList=Author.list()
        def details=['address':'xyz', phone:'123']
        authorList.each{
            it.metaClass.getDetails={->details}
        }

        render authorsList as JSON
    }
}
```

now i want this dynamically added "details" property to also get rendered as JSON. please help

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if instead of creating a setter, you just add a property like:

```
it.metaClass.details = details
```

If not, your best path is probably to create a List of Maps from your `authorsList` (adding the details key/value pair to each map), and then serialize this...

Comment: thanks for replying man, "it.metaClass.details = details" does work, can you please elaborate how is it going to help ?

Comment: I'm guessing that the Grails JSON serializer iterates through the object properties, rather than iterating through all methods that begin with 'get' and return something. As a simple example (based on a String), `def a = 'tim' ; a.metaClass.prop = 'yates' ; println a.properties.keySet()` prints out: `[prop, class, bytes, empty]`, so you can see our property is there.  Obviously String is probably handled as a separate case as you don't want `bytes` and `class` being written to your json ;-)

Comment: i tried with your suggested approach(it.metaClass.details=details), but it fails with this exception `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller can not access a member of class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ThreadManagedMetaBeanProperty$ThreadBoundGetter with modifiers "public" `

Comment: You said in your first comment that it did work...  I'm now confused...  I guess you're going to have to generate a list of maps, and serialize that instead then.

Comment: in my first comment i meant that dynamic property can be assigned this way as well, problem is with json conversion, i have edited my comment with the actual exception

Comment: and creating maps for all the objects and then manually adding the property will look very inefficient

Comment: When you have "Won't work" vs "maybe inefficient", I know which path I'd choose

Comment: i am just looking for a better solution. thanks for looking into this.

Comment: I just ran into this as well. Was able to reproduce it very simply using net.sf.json.JSONSerializer directly (which is what I think Grails is using for JSON serialization here.) `import net.sf.json.*;
def js = new JSONSerializer();
class Thing {
    def one=1;
    def two=2;
    Thing(data) {
        data.each { k,v -> this.metaClass[k] = v }
    }
}
def obj = new Thing([aye:'a', bee:'b', cee:'c']);
js.toJSON(obj)
` `Result: {"one":1,"two":2}` Anyone solve this?